# Is there a way to skip the introduction?

Tags: nier-automata

I have just barely started playing this game, but as there is no auto-save functionality and I haven't gotten far enough to save (the game told me I'd figure out how to save my game "by playing the game"), I keep having to replay the beginning every time I die.

Since I chose to play on Hard, I've died a few times now. The intro cutscene/dialogue is pretty cool, but it's getting a little repetitive, since I have to hear it every time I retry the intro mission.

Is there a way to skip this cutscene/dialogue? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this guide](http://m.gamerevolution.com/features/guide-to-reaching-the-first-save-point-in-nier-automata-on-hard-mode), as well as my own experience, *there is no way to skip the opening*. In general, you can skip cutscenes by holding the Circle button, but this is not available at any point during the opening. From the article above:

> Depending on how long you take, even getting to the first boss can take 30 minutes to an hour. **Die any time before or during this fight, and you'll get the lovely screen below followed by a quick kick in the ass that sends you all the way back to the opening cinematic**.
>
> Dying repeatedly in Nier: Automata can tilt even the strongest-willed men, especially in this first segment, **since you'll be driven all the way back to the opening lines**, which, of course, bemoan the perpetual "spiral of life and death," in a cruel twist of irony (and the knife, for that matter).

As an aside, personally, to get past the introduction level, I had to bump the difficulty down to Normal. However, the guide above gives some useful tips on how to beat it without dropping to Normal difficulty.

Comment: +1 on dropping the difficulty. There is no penalty, and you can always play it again after you beat the game on any other difficulty if you are feeling masochistic.

Comment: @CraigWright I attempted a hard playthrough after 100%ing it on normal, but bosses all oneshot you, sadly. Had to change to normal at the first Adam and Eve fight.

Comment: Since you can change the difficulty of a save file in progress from the title screen (which isn't entirely intuitive), dropping the difficulty to get past the intro and then raising it back to Hard as soon you get to a save point is quite a reasonable approach.